# Saving data from PHP to Android Database

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

I would like to save data from MySQL via PHP to my Android SQLite Database.  I am using code from other tutorials.

I make use of a Database Adapter and a Database Helper.

I tried to make this work but not sure what to do next and I also need close the database to prevent memory leak.

Can anyone tell me if this approach is correct and what to put in the PhpAdapter to insert the data to the database.

Thanks

**PhpActivity.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class PhpActivity extends Activity {
private PhpAdapter dbHelper;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView txt;
//EditText edittxt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
dbHelper = new PhpAdapter(this);
dbHelper.open();
// Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources 
// but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML. 
LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()); 
txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); 
rootLayout.addView(txt); 
//edittxt = new EditText(this);
//rootLayout.addView(edittxt);
setContentView(rootLayout); 

 // Set the text and call the connect function. 
 txt.setText("Connecting...");
//call the method to run the data retreival
txt.setText(getServerData(KEY_121));



}
public static final String KEY_121 = "http://10.101.0.64/peopledata/getAllPeopleBornAfter.php"; //i use my real ip here



private String getServerData(String returnString) {

InputStream is = null;

String result = "";
//the year data to send
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", "2007"));
//nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", edittxt.getText().toString()));

//http post
try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}

//convert response to string
try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}
//parse json data
try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String qureylog ="insert or replace into table(name, sex, birthyear) " +
                        "values('"+json_data.getString("name")+"'," +
                                " '"+json_data.getString("sex")+"'," +
                                " '"+json_data.getString("birthyear")+"')";
                dbHelper.insert(qureylog);

                Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                        ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                        ", sex: "+json_data.getString("sex")+
                        ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                );
                //Get an output to the screen
               // returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        }
}catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
return returnString;
}   


}
```

**PhpAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class PhpAdapter {

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "people";
private Context context;
private PhpAdapter dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public PhpAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public PhpAdapter open() {
    dbHelper = new PhpAdapter(context);
    //database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public void insert(String qureylog) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**DatabaseHelper**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "phpdb";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table people" +
        " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        "sex text , name text , birthyear text);";

// Method is called during creation of the database
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    // Method is called during an upgrade of the database, e.g. if you increase
    // the database version
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
            int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people");
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically looks fine. You can close you db in your activity's onDestroy().

As for the implementation of the dbAdapter youre after...doubtful that people here on SO are going to write it for you...but a good resource for simple dbAdapter example is Reto Meir's Android 2 Application Development book.

You can get at the sample code at the following link. You want to look at the code listings for chapter 7. It will help you plenty.

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-2-Application-Development.productCd-0470565527,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html

Comment: I got the book and APRESS Poro Android but Im still not sure.  I continue to write the code as what I think is should be but its not working:I changed the code: <br/> PhPAdapter.java <br/>    public void insert(String qureylog) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

Comment: with:
public long insert (String name, String sex, String birthyear) {
       ContentValues initialValues = createContentValues (sex, name, birthyear);
       return database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
 }

 private ContentValues createContentValues(String sex, String name,
 String birthyear) {
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
  values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
  values.put(KEY_SEX, sex);
  values.put(KEY_BIRTHYEAR, birthyear);
  
  
  return values;
 But its not working.

Comment: That book is **NO USE** to me in this case. It shows me what I already got in the code above an nothing more. Waste of money.